# How Do I Parameterize This Line Segment?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I'm being asked to evaluate a line integral along a path C. C is the path from $(-1,2,-2)$ to $(1,5,2)$ that consists of 3 line segments parallel to the axes; first the $z$ axis, then $x$, then $y$.

How am I supposed to get $x, y, $and $z$ in terms of $t$ when the line is in multiple disparate chunks? I'm very confused here.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do three separate integrals and add them up.

If you want to start at $(-1,2,-2)$ and move firstly parallel to the $z$ axis, you will need
$$(x,y,z)=(-1,2,t)\quad\hbox{with $t$ going from $-2$ to $2$.}$$
I'm sure you can do the others yourself.

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't come across this concept of breaking a line into chunks yet.